# How to render models using a personalized projection matrix?

Tags: opengl, 2d, 3d, graphics, animation

I'm creating a game with a great sprite demand. Out team is considering automatizing the sprite generation using 3D models. The problem is we have a very particular ortographic projection:

[image]

We have already set up a good projection matrix. The problem is none of the 3D renderer of nowadays have an option for using custom matrixes.

How is this kind of problem dealt with?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Blender for that. But it has nothing to do with matrixes, the only thing you need to set up is the ortographic camera.

See [this blog post](http://blog.gemserk.com/2011/07/20/building-2d-sprites-from-3d-models-using-blender/) for a generic approach in making graphics from 3d models. You will need the same approach except for a custom camera with orthographic view.

Comment: This is not the standard ortographic camera (120-120-120 degrees). It is a 90-135-135 instead, which is very unknown. Are you sure you can customize that on blender? I've asked that before and received negative answers.

Comment: I suppose you are talking about XYZ rotations? You can just rotate the camera in whatever degrees you want with the rotate tool to match your desired settings.

Comment: It is not a rotation. It is another kind of projection. There is no possible combination of rotations and translations that can make this coordinate system. Notice how the axis are made. x right, y up, z (up/left).

Comment: Create a simple tool that loads one 3D model, renders it exactly the way you want and then saves it into your runtime format.  Batch create all your data.  However I caution you, results may not be what you expect since you can't seem to find a 3D editor capable of previewing what you want...